# Use 3.5 mm audio port and micro USB for serial communication

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, serial-port, usb

Can I use my 3.5 mm audio port similar to the micro usb port for serial communication? I wan to create an app which connects via the audio port and can be used to control an LED? Also I have build a similar app using bluetooth module. How can I use it to communicate via micro USB?

Comment: The question is so confusing that I don't know what you really want to achieve. I understood the part about audio port and LED, but how is it connected with micro usb??

Comment: I want to achieve it via either of the two: audio port or the micro usb port whichever is easier. Basically I want to control an led through either of the ports. I have done it via bluetooth. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with **voltage levels** and with **impedances**... you risk to **fry your audio chip**!!

Now, **at your risk**: see if these link will suggest you some ideas:

http://robots-everywhere.com/re_wiki/index.php?title=Serial_on_Android_using_the_audio_port

[Android serial port via audio jack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425617/android-serial-port-via-audio-jack)

https://github.com/smartphonequadrotor/Android-Audio-Jack-Communication

**I'm not responsible** for any damage might occur to your phone due to this experimentation.

Comment: Do you know any link to a project or can you suggest how to use either the audio port or the micro USB port  for serial communication similar to bluetooth which is quite simpler?